# Motor torque calculation, about the units

Tags: motors, torque, power

This [link](http://wentec.com/unipower/calculators/power_torque.asp) shows a motor torque, power, and speed relationship, as shown below:

[image]

With regards to its units, how does kW and RPM become equivalent to N.m?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite a simple calculation, especially if you're used to dealing with metric units:

$Power=Torque \times angular Speed$ (rotational equivalent of $force \times speed$)

$Power [kW]= Torque [Nm] \times Speed [\frac{rev}{min}] \times \frac{1}{60} [\frac{min}{seconds}] \times 2π [\frac{rad}{rev}] \times 10^{-3} [\frac{kW}{W}]$

RPM= rev/min

Finally you clear torque and get the result:

$Torque [Nm]=\frac{(60 \times \frac{1000}{2π})\times Power[kW]}{ Speed [rpm]}$

And 60,000/2*π is actually 9548.8, not 9.5488, the equation online is wrong.

Comment: Equivalent explanation with different constants for the other units shown, if you are familiar and as engineers even if you are not...

Comment: @Sam Thanks. Thinking of it as Power = Force x Speed also helped, (https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/units.html), where I can see the units [Nm] x [1/s] being the same as [N] x [m/s] = [W], based on their SI-derived units.

Comment: @SamFarjamirad Yes, [m kg s^{-2}] x [ m s^{-1}] works out to be [m^{2} kg s^{-3}] = [W].

Answer (score 2):

> With regards to its units, how does kW and RPM become equivalent to N.m?

Power = force * speed.  When you're dealing with rotary motion, power = torque * rotation rate.  Their calculation of torque from HP and RPM is just a matter of getting the units consistent, and solving for torque (noting that for the power as a function of torque and rotation rate, the rotation rate must be in radians/second).